# Проблема с адаптивностью на boostrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Верстаю используя .col-lg-*
Все разрешения, что меньше 1200 начинают делать какие-то непонятно-магические действия (появляется белое окно).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Показывайте ваш код.

Comment: Как мы по-вашему должны вам помочь?

Comment: Добавьте ваш [mcve], без кода вам никто не поможет